# Select last record mysql on left join

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that stores all users connections ( date & ip ) and i want to retrieve with a single query all the users data (nickname , avatar ...) + the last record of my connections history table of this user  ...

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    `users`
        LEFT JOIN
    `connections_history` ON `users`.`id` = `connections_history`.`guid`
```

How i can proceed thx

Comment: Does `connections_history` have an AUTO_INCREMENT PK?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that `connections_history` table has an AUTO_INCREMENT column `id`:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT u.*, MAX(h.id) as hid
    FROM users u
    LEFT JOIN connections_history h ON u.id = h.guid
    GROUP BY u.id
) u
LEFT JOIN connections_history h ON h.id = u.hid
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a correlated subquery in the `ON` clause:

```
SELECT u.*, ch.*
FROM `users` u LEFT JOIN
     `connections_history` ch
      ON ch.`guid` = u.`id` AND
         ch.date = (SELECT MAX(ch2.date)
                    FROM connections_history ch2
                    WHERE ch.guid = ch2.guid
                   );
```

This formulation allows the query to take advantage of an index on `connections_history(guid, date)`.

Comment: @EvaldasBuinauskas . . . Chapter 1 of *Data Analysis Using SQL and Excel* explains the rationale behind my query formatting.  Please do not edit the formatting of my queries.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately `Mysql` does not support `window` functions, you need `Correlated sub-query` to do this.

Try something like this

```
SELECT *
FROM   users
       LEFT JOIN connections_history ch
              ON users.id = ch.guid
                 AND EXISTS (SELECT 1
                             FROM   connections_history ch1
                             WHERE  ch.guid = ch1.guid
                             HAVING Max(ch1.date) = ch.date)
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is finding the rows with max date for each guid in subquery and then join with users table.

Like this:

```
select *
from `users` u
left join (
    select *
    from `connections_history` c
    where date = (
        select max(date)
        from `connections_history` c2
        where c.`guid` = c2.`guid`
    )
) t on u.`id` = t.`guid`;
```

Comment: Not a bad solution, but it means that an index cannot be used for the `LEFT JOIN`.